# How to retrieve information from GITLAB API

Tags: javascript, node.js, gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to retrieve information from GITLAB repositories like:

- Hours spent on a sprint/Milestone;
- Hours/Time spent on each project;
- Hours/Time spent by each employee

I'm trying to use [GitBeaker](https://github.com/jdalrymple/gitbeaker) to do what I need.
Also reading [Official Doc](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/api/api_resources.md#project-resources)

But yet I can't do it.

My code so far:

```
const { Gitlab, ProjectsBundle, UsersBundle, GroupsBundle } = require('@gitbeaker/node')

const services = new GroupsBundle({
  host: 'http://example.com',
  token: 'XXXXXXXX'
})  

const projects = services.Projects.all().then((project) => {
  console.log(project)
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

I'm able to retrieve ALL projects, Groups and Users, but what If I want to retrieve only projects from a specific Group?
How may I get the time spent for a specific project?
The lib documentation names a bunch of attributes/properties available, but every time I try something different than `Projects/Groups/Users.all()` it returns `HTTPError: Response code 404 (Not Found)`.

```
const projects = services.Projects.Branches.all()  // for ProjectsBundle - 404 Not Found
const projects = services.GroupMilestones.all() // for GroupsBundle - 404 Not Found
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another bundle to get projects by the group.
See: https://github.com/jdalrymple/gitbeaker/blob/master/packages/gitbeaker-core/src/services/GroupProjects.ts

```
const services = new GroupProjects(...);
const groupProjects: ProjectSchema[] = await services.all('groupId');
```

Comment: the link is broken